# Can you transfer ETH via a C# button?

Tags: ether

I am trying to send automatic payments in C# by linking a button to web3 code for a transfer.

Essentially I need to create a function/button that sends Ether or Tokens out of my wallet when it is clicked.

So for example I could just hit the button and the transaction sends to the address I hardcoded in at the amount of gwei I chose. I would like to do this in C#.

For for example in C#, it might look something like

```
public void sendMoney(){
transfer.initiate(AMOUNT_OF_ETH, MY_PRIVATE_KEY, DestinationWallet.eth, 1 gwei, GAS_LIMIT_HERE);
}
```

Now I'd have a function that I could call anytime to send the ETH or tokens to my destination wallet.

I understand the wallet could be totally drained if the button is spammed, and that's no problem.

Is there a way to set up these auto buttons so payments could be send without using metamask?

Thanks for any input

Comment: You can HTTP RPC a geth node to do it. Works with any language, even with just `curl`.  See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC. You might want to look into sendRawTransaction

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with the blockchain, you need to chose a language/platform that implements web3 functionalities.

For example, you could set up a NODE.JS server that would handle requests from your C# calls.

Your node server should have the web3js module and a geth node running and synced with your blockchain.

[How to set up web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#installation)

Be aware: If you are on public network, you will need ether to send transactions.
I would recommend that you launch first on testnet (rinkeby or ropsten) to... well, test it, and when everything works, go to main net.

Also, as pointed out [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#other-implementations), you have other possibilities to interact with an Ethereum blockchain. Chose the one that suits you!

Edit:
With some google research (first result, you could have find it by yourself), you could use this library: [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum)